# postgres - cast timestamp format list

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, timestamp, postgresql-8.4

In postgres when i do cast(varchar_col as timestamp) how do i know which formats (ie yyyymmdd, yyyy-mm-dd...etc) are supported?

Comment: you tagged this [tag:postgresql-8.4] ; is that the version you're using? That's **literally** been unsupported since 2014.

Comment: That is determined by the [DateStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting for the database. You can change that on the fly. Though it is not a  good idea to store a timestamp as `varchar`, you should be using `timestamp` of better yet `timestamptz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not great research on your end, because it's right there in the Postgres 8.4 docs in the section of the eponymous name:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/datatype-datetime.html

> Valid input for the time stamp types consists of the concatenation of a date and a time, followed by an optional time zone, followed by an optional AD or BC. (Alternatively, AD/BC can appear before the time zone, but this is not the preferred ordering.)

So, you need to combine all input format entries from the "Date Input" table and from the "Time Input" table, which are too many to list sensibly in an answer. Makes no sense either – that's what official documentation is for.

For a more comprehensive documentation on how dates and times are parsed from strings, that's officially documented as well:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/datetime-input-rules.html